# How to plot a horizontal time series in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have  DataFrame `df` which looks like this:

```
    x0  x1    x2   x3   x4   x5   ... x10000   Date     
1    40  31.05 25.5 25.5 25.5 25   ...  33     2006-01-01 
2    35  35.75 36.5 36.5 36.5 36.5 ...  29     2007-01-01
```

where each row is a time series with regular time interval of 1 minute.

How do I plot a graph for all rows each as a time series in python?

Comment: can you write out what is your expected output looks like?

Comment: @Tserenjamts I want to plot a line graph for each row/observation, so that y-axis are the values in the table and x-axis are the regular time intervals.

Comment: `plt.plot(df.drop('Date', axis=1)).T)` maybe this is what you want

Comment: I tried with transposing the dataset but it seemed to reversed the time variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ f'x{i}': np.random.randn(10) for i in range(10)})
df['Date'] = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1979', periods=len(df), freq='D')
plt.plot(df.drop('Date', axis=1))
plt.legend(df['Date'], bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0.)
plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. But it seems like a lot of readings are missed out. The graph looks like it now has barely less than 100 different values whereas in the data there are >10000 readings.